# Promises don't have collection method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to use the collection method but it seems like i cant really use it as db.collection since db is calling connectDB and connectDB is actually a promise that returns conn which is my mongoURI. My question is what could I use to be able to call the collection method with my mongoURI to send the data from the front-end to the database?.

this is my db.js file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected : ${conn.connection.host}`);

    return conn;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

index.js (where im using the collection method):

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors"); // Importing cors
var request = require("request");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const port = 5000;
var util = require("util");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
const db = connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hey there!");
});

app.get("/Pinged", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Pinged!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
});

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));
app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  db.collection().insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send("saved to db: " + data);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

There might be some errors in the code since I dont work on the back-end side too often so please let me know if there are any.

Comment: `connectDB()` is an async function.

Comment: Yes, i know and im asking what can i use instead to call collection method

Comment: If you're using a recent enough version of Node.js which supports top-level `await`, just `await` the call to `connectDB()`.

Comment: which call exactly? I would really apreaciate it if you can show me

Comment: @william: `const db = await connectDB();`

Comment: @David i got the following error when i did that "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules". Is it bacauese of my node version?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent enough version of Node.js which supports top-level `await`, then simply `await` the `async` function call:

```
const db = await connectDB();
```

Alternatively, if you can't use top-level `await`, you can resolve the Promise when you need to.  For example:

```
app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  db.then(conn => {
    conn.collection().insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      res.send("saved to db: " + data);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm not 100% sure about handling these connections, and another option could be to remove the top-level call to `connectDB()` entirely and invoke it on each request:

```
app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  connectDB().then(db => {
    db.collection().insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      res.send("saved to db: " + data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: When i used the seconde solution I got an error saying "TypeError: conn.collection is not a function"

Comment: Also, regarding the third solution I would get the error "TypeError: db.collection is not a function"

Comment: @william: At this point you may be asking more about Mongoose itself than about async and promises.  And I have very little knowledge of the former.  Is there an example or documentation you're following?

Comment: Not really it's just that i have been working on the back-end the past 3 days and whenever i get an error i would search it up. And this was the last one i got :)

Comment: @william: If you aren't using any specific documentation or example then what do you expect `.collection()` to do and why?  The error is telling you that it's not a function.  So why specifically did you think it would be?  Either way, it sounds like the subject of the question is moving from how to await a Promise to how to use Mongoose, which is a different question entirely.

Comment: Yeah, your right. I will look more into mongoose in that case, and thank you for your answer!